# Select the value of an attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have the following table:

```
<table summary='' id='table_csrdownloadcenter'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>text1</th>
<th>text2</th>      
<th>text3</th>
<th>text4</th>
<th>text5</th>
<th>text6</th>
<th>text7</th>
<th>text8</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 

<tr id='nom_du_pdf'>
<td class='dc-date'></td>
<td class='dc-dl'></td>                                             
<td class='dc-title'></td>
<td class='dc-area'></td>
<td class='dc-category'></td>
<td class='dc-file'></td>
<td class='dc-ranking'></td>
<td class='dc-checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='chk"+PathFile[i]+"' ></td>
</tr>

<tr id='nom_du_pdf2'>
<td class='dc-date'></td>
<td class='dc-dl'></td>                                             
<td class='dc-title'></td>
<td class='dc-area'></td>
<td class='dc-category'></td>
<td class='dc-file'></td>
<td class='dc-ranking'></td>
<td class='dc-checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='chk"+PathFile[i]+"' ></td>
</tr>


</tbody>
<table>
```

For **each** `<tr>` I would like to save in a string the value of the name attribute in the 8th `<td>`
I tried this :

```
function DownloadZip()
{
$('.DownloadZip').click(function(){

        var res = "";
    $('#table_csrdownloadcenter').find("tbody").find("tr").find(td:nth-child(8)).find("input").each(function(){
       res = $(this).attr("name").text();
       alert(res);
    }
});
}
```

Can anyone help me to make this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate each `tr`, then check the `8th` td's `input`

```
var mappedAttributes = $("#table_csrdownloadcenter tr").map(function() {
    return $("td:eq(7) input", this).attr("name");
}).get();
```

This creates an array of each of the `name` attribute values.

To create a string:

```
var str = "";
$("#table_csrdownloadcenter tr").each(function() {
    str += $("td:eq(7) input", this).attr("name");
})
```

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm but if i want to get the names of the checked checkboxes , i tried to write input:checked and it does not work... any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `text()` method , the **[`attr("name")`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** will return the value of name attribute, also you are missing `""`

```
function DownloadZip()
{
$('.DownloadZip').click(function(){    
    var res = "";
    $('#table_csrdownloadcenter').find("tbody").find("tr").find("td:nth-child(8)").find("input").each(function(){
    //                                                       ---^-----       ---^----
       res = $(this).attr("name");
       alert(res);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
res = $(this).attr("name");
```

instead of:

```
res = $(this).attr("name").text();
```

since `$(this).attr("name")` already give you the string that contain the value of your `name` attribute.

[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a jQuery method and only jQuery object can utilize that method but `$(this).attr("name")` give you a string so obviously a string cannot apply jQuery method.

Also you're missing quotes around your selector here

```
find(td:nth-child(8))
```

It should be

```
find('td:nth-child(8)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td.dc-checkbox").find("input").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("name"));
});
```