# Select only checked boxes with Jquery Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

With the following block of code :

```
function DownloadZip()
{
$('.DownloadZip').click(function(){

var str = "";
$("#table_csrdownloadcenter tr").each(function() {
    str += $("td:eq(7) input[type=checkbox]:checked", this).attr("name");
})

console.log(str);
});
}
```

i try to save in a string the "name" attributes of **every checked boxes**.
My problem is this block of code saves in "str" the string "undefined" when the box is not checked. I don't want it to save anything if the box is not checked.

Can you help me to achieve this ? thanks

PS: for information, this is how my table looks like:

```
<table summary='' id='table_csrdownloadcenter'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>text1</th>
<th>text2</th>      
<th>text3</th>
<th>text4</th>
<th>text5</th>
<th>text6</th>
<th>text7</th>
<th>text8</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 

<tr id='nom_du_pdf'>
<td class='dc-date'></td>
<td class='dc-dl'></td>                                             
<td class='dc-title'></td>
<td class='dc-area'></td>
<td class='dc-category'></td>
<td class='dc-file'></td>
<td class='dc-ranking'></td>
<td class='dc-checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='chk"+PathFile[i]+"' ></td>
</tr>

<tr id='nom_du_pdf2'>
<td class='dc-date'></td>
<td class='dc-dl'></td>                                             
<td class='dc-title'></td>
<td class='dc-area'></td>
<td class='dc-category'></td>
<td class='dc-file'></td>
<td class='dc-ranking'></td>
<td class='dc-checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='chk"+PathFile[i]+"' ></td>
</tr>


</tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Why are you asking same question again? possible duplicate of [Select the value of an attribute in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020421/select-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-jquery). Guys have already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$("#table_csrdownloadcenter tr td:nth-child(8) input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    str += $(this).attr("name");
})
```

Comment: @Satpal But its a new question to me, I have not used this kind of selectors in my projects. :) Learnt something new.! :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Good for you. Then this is much better `$("#table_csrdownloadcenter td.dc-checkbox :checkbox:checked")` also visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020421/select-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-jquery you will learn something new

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for the link.. :) oohh.. The same OP asked that question. Any way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#table_csrdownloadcenter td.dc-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function()       {
    str += $(this).attr("name");
})
```